# Problem with gazebo differential drive plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, differential-drive

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I want to launch a gazebo (11) world and model in ROS Noetic. This also contains differential drive controller defined as follows:

```
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
     <robotNamespace />
     <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
     <updateRate>10</updateRate>
     <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
     <leftJoint>left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
     <rightJoint>right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
     <wheelSeparation>0.5380</wheelSeparation>
     <wheelDiameter>0.2410</wheelDiameter>
     <torque>20</torque>
     <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
     <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
     <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
     <robotBaseFrame>chassis</robotBaseFrame>
     <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
     <publishWheelJointState>false</publishWheelJointState>
     <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
     <wheelAcceleration>0</wheelAcceleration>
     <wheelTorque>5</wheelTorque>
     <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
     <publishTf>1</publishTf>
  </plugin>
```

But when launched, I am getting `libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so` not found error. If I use `libDiffDrivePlugin.so` (as this binary is present at the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`) , I get following error

```
[Err] [DiffDrivePlugin.cc:52] DiffDrive plugin missing <left_joint> element
[Err] [DiffDrivePlugin.cc:55] DiffDrive plugin missing <right_joint> element
```

I tried to follow the steps mentioned [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins). Is there any update with respect to how the default plugins work in Gazebo 11? Because it is working in Gazebo 9 and melodic.

Thanks and regards,
Shreyas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355735/problem-with-gazebo-differential-drive-plugin/) by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem by installing gazebo-plugins package.

`sudo apt install ros-noetic-gazebo-plugins`

---

Originally posted by [elementaryshr](https://answers.ros.org/users/41127/elementaryshr/) with karma: 28 on 2020-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1